# How do you wrap a React state variable in a function call?

Tags: reactjs

I have some state that gets updated async that I would like to wrap inside a function call (to modularize the code).

Concretely, I have a `isLoggedIn` state variable that I would like to retrieve with a function call inside a React component. So far I have:

## firebase.js

```js
function userLoggedIn() {
  const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false);

  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
    if (user == null) {
      console.log("No user logged in.");
    } else {
      console.log(`User ${user.uid} authenticated!`);
      setIsLoggedIn(true);
    }
  });

  return isLoggedIn;
}

export default userLoggedIn;
```

And I have a separate component that I would like to get this `isLoggedIn` state from:

## AuthenticatedRoute.js

```js
const AuthenticatedRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
  const isLoggedin = userLoggedIn();

  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={(props) =>
        isLoggedIn ? (
          <Component {...props} />
        ) : (
          <Redirect
            to={{ pathname: "/login", state: { from: props.location } }}
          />
        )
      }
    />
  );
};
```

It works fine on page load, but if I log out (and `user = null`) `isLoggedIn` doesn't change to False.

This all works fine if I inline the function body inside `AuthenticatedRoute`: in general, how does one achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried putting `setIsLoggedIn(false);` in the `if (user == null)` block?

Comment: Doh yes that worked. Thanks!

Comment: You should note this is likely only working accidentally because your function's name begins with `use` so I think the linter sees it as a custom hook, and you've called it from the body of the functional component. Also, apply boolean zen, just `setIsLoggedIn(!!user)` in the `onAuthStateChanged` callback handler.